# Ebiten wasm won't load

Tags: go, webassembly

I'm trying to load Ebiten into Wasm using the command `go run github.com/hajimehoshi/wasmserve@latest .`, but when I go to try and load the `localhost:8080` I just get an indefinite black screen. The browser I'm using is Librewolf, and I have all my protections turned off as well as UBlock, so I don't know if there's something else that I'm missing.

Here is my code incase it helps:

```
package main

import (
    "image/color"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/image/font"
    "golang.org/x/image/font/opentype"

    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/examples/resources/fonts"

    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/text"
    "github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/v2/vector"
)

type score float32

// Window constants
const (
    WIN_WIDTH  = 1000
    WIN_HEIGHT = 450
)

var BG_COL = color.RGBA{130, 130, 130, 1}

// Ball constants
const (
    BALL_RAD = 10

    BALL_VEL = 3

    BALL_STARTX = WIN_WIDTH / 2
    BALL_STARTY = BALL_RAD

    BALL_ANTIALIASING = true
)

var BALL_COL = color.White

// Paddle constants
const (
    PADDLE_WIDTH  = 20
    PADDLE_HEIGHT = 100

    PADDLE_OFFSET_X = 10
    PADDLE_OFFSET_Y = 5

    LPADDLE_X = PADDLE_OFFSET_X
    RPADDLE_X = WIN_WIDTH - PADDLE_WIDTH - PADDLE_OFFSET_X

    PADDLE_VEL = 20

    PADDLE_ANTIALIASING = true
)

var PADDLE_COL = color.White

// Paddle scoring constants
const (
    PADDLE_SCORE_FONT_SIZE = 40

    PADDLE_SCORE_POS_OFFSET = 30

    PADDLE_SCORE_POS_Y = 50
)

var SCORE_COL = color.White

type Game struct {
    // Ball variables
    ball_x float32
    ball_y float32

    vel_x, vel_y float32

    // Paddle variables
    lpaddle_y, rpaddle_y float32

    // Paddle scoring variables
    lpaddle_score, rpaddle_score score

    // Font
    mplusNormalFont font.Face
}

// Game logic loop
func (g *Game) Update() error {
    // Collision

    // Collision between the ball and either paddle
    if (g.ball_x-BALL_RAD <= LPADDLE_X+PADDLE_WIDTH && g.ball_y >= g.lpaddle_y && g.ball_y <= g.lpaddle_y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) || // Ball collides with left paddle
        (g.ball_x >= RPADDLE_X-PADDLE_WIDTH && g.ball_y >= g.rpaddle_y && g.ball_y <= g.rpaddle_y+PADDLE_HEIGHT) { // Ball collides with right paddle
        g.vel_x *= -1 // Reverse ball dir
    }

    // Collision between the ball and the top/bottom walls
    if g.ball_y-BALL_RAD < 0 || g.ball_y+BALL_RAD > WIN_HEIGHT {
        g.vel_y *= -1 // Reverse ball dir
    }

    // Scoring

    // Left paddle scores (ball hits right wall)
    if g.ball_x+BALL_RAD > WIN_WIDTH {
        g.lpaddle_score += 1 // Give left paddle a point
        g.vel_x *= -1        // Reverse ball dir
    }

    // Right paddle scores (ball hits left wall)
    if g.ball_x-BALL_RAD < 0 {
        g.rpaddle_score += 1 // Give right paddle a point
        g.vel_x *= -1        // Reverse ball dir
    }

    // Movement

    // Increment the x/y position of the ball the the velocity
    g.ball_x += g.vel_x
    g.ball_y += g.vel_y

    // Move the right paddle using the Up Arrow key as long as the paddle is in the screen
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyUp) && g.rpaddle_y > 0+PADDLE_OFFSET_Y {
        g.rpaddle_y -= PADDLE_VEL
    }

    // Move the right paddle using the Down Arrow key as long as the paddle is in the screen
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyDown) &&
        g.rpaddle_y+PADDLE_HEIGHT+PADDLE_OFFSET_Y < WIN_HEIGHT {
        g.rpaddle_y += PADDLE_VEL
    }

    // Move the left paddle using the W key as long as the paddle is in the screen
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyW) && g.lpaddle_y > 0+PADDLE_OFFSET_Y {
        g.lpaddle_y -= PADDLE_VEL
    }

    // Move the left paddle using the S key as long as the paddle is in the screen
    if ebiten.IsKeyPressed(ebiten.KeyS) && g.lpaddle_y+PADDLE_HEIGHT+PADDLE_OFFSET_Y < WIN_HEIGHT {
        g.lpaddle_y += PADDLE_VEL
    }

    return nil
}

// Game draw loop
func (g *Game) Draw(screen *ebiten.Image) {
    // Draw background
    vector.DrawFilledRect(screen, 0, 0, WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, BG_COL, false)

    // Draw ball
    vector.DrawFilledCircle(
        screen,
        g.ball_x,
        g.ball_y,
        BALL_RAD,
        BALL_COL,
        BALL_ANTIALIASING,
    )

    // Draw right paddle
    vector.DrawFilledRect(
        screen,
        RPADDLE_X,
        g.rpaddle_y,
        PADDLE_WIDTH,
        PADDLE_HEIGHT,
        PADDLE_COL,
        PADDLE_ANTIALIASING,
    )

    // Draw left paddle
    vector.DrawFilledRect(
        screen,
        LPADDLE_X,
        g.lpaddle_y,
        PADDLE_WIDTH,
        PADDLE_HEIGHT,
        PADDLE_COL,
        PADDLE_ANTIALIASING,
    )

    // Draw right paddle score
    text.Draw(
        screen,
        g.rpaddle_score.to_string(),
        g.mplusNormalFont,
        WIN_WIDTH/2-PADDLE_SCORE_POS_OFFSET-PADDLE_SCORE_FONT_SIZE/4,
        PADDLE_SCORE_POS_Y,
        SCORE_COL,
    )

    // Draw right paddle score
    text.Draw(
        screen,
        g.lpaddle_score.to_string(),
        g.mplusNormalFont,
        WIN_WIDTH/2+PADDLE_SCORE_POS_OFFSET-PADDLE_SCORE_FONT_SIZE/4,
        PADDLE_SCORE_POS_Y,
        SCORE_COL,
    )
}

// No clue
func (g *Game) Layout(outsideWidth, outsideHeight int) (screenWidth, screenHeight int) {
    return WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT
}

func main() {
    game := &Game{} // Game

    // Ball variables
    game.ball_x = BALL_STARTX
    game.ball_y = BALL_STARTY

    game.vel_x, game.vel_y = BALL_VEL, BALL_VEL

    // Paddle variables
    game.lpaddle_y, game.rpaddle_y = PADDLE_OFFSET_Y, PADDLE_OFFSET_Y

    // Paddle scoring variables
    game.lpaddle_score, game.rpaddle_score = 0, 0

    // Initilize font
    tt, err := opentype.Parse(fonts.MPlus1pRegular_ttf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    game.mplusNormalFont, err = opentype.NewFace(tt, &opentype.FaceOptions{
        Size:    PADDLE_SCORE_FONT_SIZE,
        DPI:     72,
        Hinting: font.HintingVertical,
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Create window
    ebiten.SetWindowSize(WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
    ebiten.SetWindowTitle("Gopong")

    // Game loop
    if err := ebiten.RunGame(game); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func (n score) to_string() string {
    buf := [11]byte{}
    pos := len(buf)
    i := int64(n)
    signed := i < 0
    if signed {
        i = -i
    }
    for {
        pos--
        buf[pos], i = '0'+byte(i%10), i/10
        if i == 0 {
            if signed {
                pos--
                buf[pos] = '-'
            }
            return string(buf[pos:])
        }
    }
}
```